# formatYLabel is not working on expo react-native-chart-kit

Tags: react-native, charts, expo

I am using a line chart, I want to have on the yaxis 3 values, less, same and more.
I am trying to do this with `formatYLabel` but it's not working, here is my code

```
   <LineChart
      data={{
        labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
        datasets: [{
          data: [
            0,
            1,
            2,
            2,
            1,
            2,
          ]
        }]
      }}......

      chartConfig={{
        formatYLabel: (yValue) => {
          const labels = ["less", "same", "more"];
          return labels[parseInt(yValue, 10)];
        },
```

And here is the line chart
[image]